# How to extract the statistics of some youtube channels?

Tags: r, date, youtube-api

I am using R code to extract the statistics of some YouTube channels.
I am using the `tuber` package  and specifically `get_all_video_stats` function.

My problem is that I only want the statistics published for the last 6 months and since the creation of the channel.

Is it possible to do?

Comment: This question is very general and consequently hard to answer. Try to narrow it down a bit, show what you tried and ask about the problems and show-stoppers you encounter.

Answer (score 0):

Use `lubridate` library to filter only last 6 months of video statistics data.

```
library(tuber)
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

## Enter your actual credetionals (stub)
## Not run:
yt_oauth("<Enter your app_id>", 
         "<Enter your app_secret>")

## End(Not run)

vs <- get_all_channel_video_stats("UCbZRdTukTCjFan4onn04sDA")

# "Since creation" data are in vs dataframe
cat("Published since creation: ", nrow(vs))

# last six month data are in vs6 dataframe
vs6 <- vs %>% mutate(publication_date = as_date(publication_date)) %>% 
  filter(publication_date >= today() - ceiling(365.25 / 2))
cat("Published in last six month:", nrow(vs6))
```